# "How to pass GregorianCalendar class object to a different class method ?"

Tags: java, class, constructor, nullpointerexception, gregorian-calendar

1. I want to create a student record using a method that is able to
   take input from user about student details . My class Student should
   consists of following fields : short semester, 
                          full name,
                          registration number etc
       .registration number of a student = concatenation of year and student number.
       Eg year at which student joined = 2023,
          student no. = 80,
          So registration number = 2380

Plus I have been tasked to input date using class GregorianCalendar

INSIDE STUDENT CLASS:

```
import java.util.*;

class Student2{

    String fullname;
    GregorianCalendar date;
    short semester;

    Student2()
    {

    }

    Student2(String name,short sem, GregorianCalendar Date)
    {
        fullname = name;
        semester=sem;
        date = Date;
    }

    int years = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    String year = Integer.toString(years);
    String Studno = Integer.toString(80);

    String y1= year.substring(0,3);
    String Reg = y1.concat(Studno);

    int reg = Integer.parseInt(Reg);

    void Studarry()
    {
         int n=5,i;
         Student2[] stuarry = new Student2[10];
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             System.out.println("Enter name sem year month day gpa cgpa\n");
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             String name = sc.nextLine();

             short sem2 = sc.nextShort();
             int year2 = sc.nextInt();
             int month2 = sc.nextInt();
             int day2=sc.nextInt()

             GregorianCalendar gc2 = new GregorianCalendar(year2,month2,day2);


             stuarry[i] = new Student2(name,sem2,gc2);

         }
    }

    void Display()
    {

    }

}
```

INSIDE DRIVER CLASS:

```
public class Greg2{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
         Student2 starr = new Student2();
         starr.Studarry();
    }

}
```

ERRORS :

- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

  ```
  at oop2/lab5.Student2.<init>(Greg2.java:23)


  at oop2/lab5.Greg2.main(Greg2.java:68)
  ```

Comment: You are attempting to initialize `years` before `date` is initialized. This means that `date` is still null and calling a method on it will lead to a NullPointerException. It seems like the code you have between the `Student2` constructor and the `Studarry` methods should be moved into the `Student2` constructor because as they are currently, the lines are executed as soon as an instance of `Student2` is created. You also have to actually combine and save those variables to the `fullname`.

Comment: If you don't understand why the code doesn't work as is, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: *I have been tasked to input date using class GregorianCalendar* Do teachers who ask such horrible requirements never go away? The `GregorianCalendar` class is poorly designed and very long outdated. No one should use it. Teachers least of all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Class name versus variable name

> `date = Date;`

`Date` with an uppercase `D` is the name of a class, not a variable. Instead you should have defined the name of the argument being passed as `date` not `Date`. This line becomes `date = date ;`. The compiler can distinguish between the argument and the member variable. If you want more clarity for the reader, you can say `this.date = date ;`.

But that is a poor name for a variable. Because there is indeed two classes bundled with Java named `Date`, both related to `GregorianCalendar`, I suggest avoiding the use of `date` as a variable name for `GregorianCalendar` object – just too confusing.

## *java.time*

The `GregorianCalendar` is a terrible class. It was supplanted entirely years ago by the *java.time* classes. Specifically, [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Both classes represent a moment as seen through the wall-clock time of some particular region (a time zone).

However, both classes are *not* meant for your purpose. You want only a date, without a time-of-day and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So `LocalDate` fits your needs.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( year , month , day ) ;
```

## Constructor

```
int years = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String year = Integer.toString(years);
String Studno = Integer.toString(80);
…
```

These lines are floating around, not placed inside a method. They should have been put inside the constructor of your method.

Why is there a class named `Greg2`? Did you mean a specific student? If so, Greg should be represented by values assigned to an *instance* of a `Student` class.

What is with all the `2` characters at the end of names? Naming is important; get that straight and you will be half-way to a solution.

So most of this code is a mess. **Try again from scratch.** Look up other code examples, such as on Stack Overflow, in the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), or in the textbook for your class of this homework assignment.

Learn about *separation of concerns*. One class should be just about representing a student. Another class should represent your app, and hold the `main` method. Use a `Collection` to gather the newly instantiated `Student` classes into a roster, possibly making a class `Roster` if you have other roster-related responsibilities.

Lastly, take baby steps. Add one little thing at a time, see that it runs properly. Use `System.out.println` to verify values. Do not try to write all the code at once.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NullPointerException` comes from this line:

```
    int years = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Field initializers like this one are executed *before* the constructor. So when you create a `Student2` object using `new Student2()`, the above line is created while the `date` field is still `null`, and therefore the call to `date.get()` throw the exception.

Instead move the initialization of `years` into the constructor, after you have assigned an object to `date`.

As others have said too, the `GregorianCalendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. If it wasn’t for a lazy teacher apperently with no clue of what has been going on with Java the last more than 5 years, you shouldn’t use it. Never ever.

Answer (score 1):

Mistakes corrected as-

1) Bought field initializers inside my constructor to get rid of NullpointerException as said by ( Basil Bourque , Ole V.V. )

2) created array of student objects in main and called method Stduarry on them .

3) Variable name Date changed to gc

```
import java.util.*;
```

INSIDE STUDENT CLASS:

```
class Student22{

    String fullname;
    GregorianCalendar date;
    short semester;
    int reg;

    Student22()
    {

    }

    Student22(String name,short sem, GregorianCalendar gc)
    {
        fullname = name;
        semester=sem;
        date = gc;

         int years = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

         String year = Integer.toString(years);
         System.out.println(year);
         String Studno = Integer.toString(80);

         String y1= year.substring(2,4);

         System.out.println(y1);
         String Reg = y1.concat(Studno);
         System.out.println(Reg);

         reg = Integer.parseInt(Reg);
         System.out.println(reg);
    }



     void Studarry(int n)
    {



             System.out.println("Enter name sem year month day \n");
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

             fullname = sc.nextLine();
             System.out.println(fullname);

             semester = sc.nextShort();
             int year2 = sc.nextInt();
             int month2 = sc.nextInt();
             int day2=sc.nextInt();

             GregorianCalendar gc2 = new GregorianCalendar(year2,month2,day2);  
             date= gc2;


             int years = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

             String year = Integer.toString(years);
             String Studno = Integer.toString(n);

             String y1= year.substring(0,3);
             String Reg = y1.concat(Studno);

             reg = Integer.parseInt(Reg);

             Display();
     }

    void Display()
    {
         System.out.println(fullname);
         System.out.println(semester);
         System.out.println(reg);
         System.out.println(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    }


}
```

INSIDE DRIVER CLASS:

```
 public class Greg2{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 

         System.out.println("Please enter a Firstname , MiddleName & Lastname separated by spaces");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String name = sc.nextLine();

         GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2018,7,22);
         Student22 s = new Student22(name,(short)3,gc);
         s.Display();

         int i,j,n;
         System.out.println("Enter n\n");
         n = sc.nextInt();
         Student22[] starr = new Student22[n+1];
         for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
         {
             starr[j]= new Student22(); 
             starr[j].Studarry(j);
         }



    }


}
```